# developing module with drupal

Tags: php, drupal

I have a website which is up and running on drupal. Its product based website. I developed by creating my own tables and writing php code using php filters. I never used module concepts. Since the site is running well, so i am thinking to move to module concept.  so wanted some help here, like how to do it.. i have gone through module development concepts also.

requirement.
1. Admin should be able to create new products like Mobile, Camera.
2. He should be able to define product properties and properties for which user will rate on.
3. Admin/ second admin should be able to create new sub products under products like mobile - nokia 8850 , nokia 9980 where he enters details of product properties also.
4. A listing page for all the sun products under main product. and from listing page we go to to main sub product page where user rates the product.

My confusion : should i create a new table or drupal takes care of all the requirements. and how do i start with it.

update : clear picture of requirement
ex :
1. 1st i add a product **"MOBILES"**
2. Then i add properties for this main product.
3. Then i start adding sub products under **MOBILES** i.e nokia 1100, samsumg 2200 and etc.
while adding sub products, in this page it gives me a text box for all the propeties i defined while creating the main product **MOBILES** . So is this possible using CCK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right to consider using modules and following the "Drupal way". Use CCK + Views and Drupal will take care of the table maintenance and querying for you.

As already mentioned, you will need to get familiar with the CCK module. This module will allow you to create new "content types", which in your example would be the different product types and their attributes. Here is a good overview [video](http://gotdrupal.com/videos/understanding-drupal-content-types-cck) on CCK. With CCK you can define new content types and Drupal will create the basic content creation forms for you and hide spare you from all the database details when you're working with it.

The [Views](http://gotdrupal.com/videos/drupal-views-tutorial) module is essentially a query builder and will allow you to create views of your content. There are all sorts of related modules that can help you render your data as charts, grids, lists, slideshows, tables, etc.

There is a slight learning curve but once you get past it you'll be able to build new things pretty quick.

Update: Just another thought, if you are really needing to create some kind of classification system you should look at [Taxonomies](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/taxonomy).

Comment: so to go step wise.
1. use CCK to create custom fields(properties) and add various products.

Comment: I think what you will need to do is create a new Content Type called: Mobiles with the various fields you care about. Each of the phones would be a single record of type Mobiles. I'm not sure if it's a good idea to create a hierarchy of phones because something like brand could just be a field that you filter on.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you could do all of this with modules, without needing to do any php coding at all.  Check out (if you haven't already) [cck](http://drupal.org/project/cck), [views](http://drupal.org/project/views), and [fivestar](http://drupal.org/project/fivestar).

Comment: @pradeep: If you are selling these products, also check out [ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart).  This is a fairly huge module that is the only really viable way to do e-commerce (at least in Drupal 6).  It integrates with CCK, so you end up creating CCK content types that are products or classes of products.  Learn CCK first, then ease into ubercart.  It will take a while to learn all this stuff, but you end up with a much more secure and robust system.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your update, sounds like CCK and [Node Hierarchy](http://drupal.org/project/nodehierarchy) should do everything you need.